# How do I set the value of an ancestor using a binding? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is always a need to change a small detail in the attached style. But these detail properties are set inside the template. For example, style from nuget:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid TabNavigation="Local">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TabPanel Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0" ZIndex="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsItemsHost="True" TabIndex="1" Background="Transparent" />
                <Border Margin="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryLightBrush}" />
                <Border Name="Border" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" TabNavigation="Local" DirectionalNavigation="Contained" TabIndex="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryLightBrush}">
                    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="2,24,2,2" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

So to change border radius you either need to completely override the template from the original style or find another way.

I want to just find target ancestor element and set value to, using binding in `OneWayToSource` mode.

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlBase}" SomeProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=OneWayToSource, Path=CornerRadius}">
    <!--some stuff-->
</TabControl>
```

I tried to create AttachedProperty, that will contains my value by default, but it cannot contain binding.

I want to find out if it is possible to make a universal property to which binding could be assigned? Or maybe there is an easier way to do what I want.

Comment: The Border you find with FindAncestor is one that surrounds your TabControl, it is not a Border in the ControlTemplate of the TabControl. So it should be defined in your own XAML. Why would you want to set its CornerRadius in such a complicated way?

If you want to change some detail of a Visual inside the control template, and that detail that is not exposed through a DP or a Style property you need to get access in code to that control template child for example using `GetTemplateChild` or by the `GetChild` and `GetChildrenCount` VisualTreeHelper methods

Comment: I don't want to use c# code for visual elements. But, apparently, you will have to. I thought someone would tell me an easy way to access the properties of parent elements via xaml. But judging by my experiments, indeed, FindAncestor cannot access these elements.

Comment: I just wanted to stress that RelSource FindAncestor goes into the opposite direction, it goes up the tree and you want to dig into.
It should work with a custom attached property of type CornerRadius btw. When you bind Border.CornerRadius inside the Control Template to that AP and set the AP to the TabControl in your XAML, it should work (maybe inside the Control Template you need RelativeSource Binding mode TemplatedParent or FindAncestor so that it resolves the property attaced to the tab control and not to the border)..

Comment: Yes, thanks, I knew this way, but I can't change the template and it doesn't have an attached property for corner radius.